# Using bootstrap tooltip in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap tooltip in asp.net but it does not work and i am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
     <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
     <form id="form1" runat="server">    
         <br />
         <br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"  
                                                  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
             });
        </script>           
    </form>    
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be missing a reference like this one depending on which Bootstrap version are you using, if you are using 3.x then you are missing this

```
<link href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

also you are missing the `ToolTip` attribute in your `TextBox1` control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" ToolTip="My tooltip text" runat="server" />
```

Comment: is there a way to make the tooltip to appear only on  a onclick event?

Comment: Change it to a bootstrap popover.  Don't forget to mark this as answered.

Comment: Yes: `data-trigger="click"`. Read the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options